# Assume Prototype Library When Running JSLint

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, jslint

I have a some JavaScript files I am trying to run through JSLint. The files make use of [Prototype JS v1.6](http://www.prototypejs.org/). I don't want to run prototype-1.6.js through JSLint as this creates lots of warnings I am not interested in, I only want to run my own source files. However, if I exclude the prototype source when running JSLint I get lots of warning about undefined classes etc.

Can anyone tell me how to make JSLint 'assume' prototype is present so it doesn't warn with false-positives about prototype?

Comment: Perhaps you could just filter out warnings from the prototype.js file using `grep -v prototype.js` or something like that?

Comment: That's exactly my current approach, was just hoping there was a more configurable way of doing this as grep doesn't run so well in a maven build. Interestingly there is an adapted version of JSLint at link below that can 'assumr prototype' but is not open source.

Comment: http://webster.cs.washington.edu/jslint/

Comment: prototype is an enhancement request for JSHint https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issuesearch?state=open&q=prototype#issue/80

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent JSLint warnings for globals that are defined by a third-party library this way:

```
/*jslint <your usual jslint options> */
/*global foo, bar, baz */
```

So for Prototype you'd use something like `/*global $, $$, Ajax, Class, ...`.

It's a bit of a pain to copy-paste this into the header of all your JS files, though. You have  a few options for avoiding that:

- Run JSLint from the command line ([e.g. with Grunt](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-linter)), and set the globals centrally in the options you pass in there.
- Use JSHint, which supports a [`prototypejs: true` option](http://www.jshint.com/docs/#prototypejs) that automatrically predefines all those globals for you. Many people actually prefer JSHint since it's more flexible than JSLint.
- Use the fork of JSLint from Scruffers's [link above](http://webster.cs.washington.edu/jslint/) (just download its copy of *jslint.js*), which similarly adds a `prototype: true` option.